# Folder View in C# Form

Tags: c#, programming-languages, directory

In an attempt to learn C#, I am trying to develop Picasa Like Application to display Photographs from my Library.

Would it be possible to display folders as in Picasa Using C# ?

Any help would be highly helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to get list of [files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.getfiles.aspx)/[folders](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.getdirectories.aspx), then show them how you like. Especially this will be nice using WPF

Comment: Thanks a lot. is it possible to select A Directory and list all the sub directories in a the Design Form ?